# Cosmos DB - can't use a property (array) with IN Keyword

Tags: azure-cosmosdb

I'm attempting to query for several documents at once, using some properties that were found on the first document, similar to a TSQL left join on *property value*.

My attempt in CosmosDB:

```
select c from assets
join ver on c.versions
where c.id = '123' OR c.id IN ver.otherIds   
--NOTE: ver.otherIds is an array
```

The query above results in a syntax error, stating it doesn't understand `ver.otherIds`. The [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/how-to-sql-query#in-keyword) state the syntax to be `where c.id in ("123","456"...)`

Things I've tried to work around this:

- Attempted Custom UDF that takes in the array generates the syntax wanted Ex) `["123,"456"] --> "("123", "456")`
- Attempted using `array_contains(ver.otherIds, c.id)`
- Attempted sub query approach, which produced a "The cardinality of a scalar subquery result set cannot be greater than one" error:

```
select value c from c
where array_contains((select ... that produces array), c.id)
```

None of the above worked.

I can, of course, pull the first asset, then generate a second query to pull the rest, but I'd rather not do that. I can also just de-normalize all the data, but without giving specifics to my scenario, it would end up being a very bad idea.

Any ideas?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Hi,does my answer helps you?

Answer (score 1):

You could use your second scenario:[ARRAY_CONTAINS](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/how-to-sql-query#array-functions).

My sample document:

```
[
    {
        "id": "1",
        "versions": [
            {
                "otherIds": [
                    "1",
                    "2",
                    "3"
                ]
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "id": "2",
        "versions": [
            {
                "otherIds": [
                    "1",
                    "2",
                    "3"
                ]
            },
            {
                "otherIds": [
                    "123",
                    "2",
                    "3"
                ]
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "id": "123",
        "versions": [
            {
                "otherIds": [
                    "1",
                    "2",
                    "3"
                ]
            },
            {
                "otherIds": [
                    "123",
                    "2",
                    "3"
                ]
            }
        ]
    }
]
```

SQL：

```
SELECT distinct c.id,c.versions FROM c
join ver in  c.versions
where c.id="123" or array_contains(ver.otherIds,c.id,false)
```

**ARRAY_CONTAINS** function can specify if the match is full or partial.

Comment: Hi Jay, Unfortunately this answer is something I've already tried - it doesn't work. The answer I came up with is to move the link down to the child object instead of storing an array in the parent. Then i can search for `c.id ='foo' or c.parentId = 'foo'`